List of temporary/intermediate file types
I’ve compiled a list of LaTeX-related temporary/intermediate file types, with the help of some AI. Could you please suggest any improvements or point out any missing files?
Thanks in advance!

.acr


Purpose: Acronym list data file, generated by the glossaries package when using the acronym option.
Obtained: Generated when acronyms are used with glossaries.
Safe to Remove: Yes


.aux


Purpose: Stores auxiliary information (cross-references, citations).
Obtained: Generated by LaTeX compilation.
Safe to Remove: Yes


.bbl


Purpose: Contains formatted bibliography data.
Obtained: Generated by BibTeX or Biber from a .bib file. But can be also made by hand.
Safe to Remove: Only if a .bib source is present.


.blg


Purpose: BibTeX or Biber log file for bibliographic processing.
Obtained: Generated by BibTeX or Biber.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.fdb_latexmk


Purpose: Stores data for latexmk to avoid redundant runs.
Obtained: Generated by latexmk.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.fls


Purpose: Lists files read and written during compilation.
Obtained: Generated by LaTeX tools for dependency tracking.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.gls


Purpose: Glossary data file.
Obtained: Generated for glossary creation tools like makeglossaries.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.idx


Purpose: Index raw data for makeindex.
Obtained: Generated during LaTeX compilation when indexing commands are used.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.ilg


Purpose: Log file for makeindex.
Obtained: Created by makeindex.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.ind


Purpose: Processed index file.
Obtained: Generated by makeindex.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.lof


Purpose: Stores the list of figures data.
Obtained: Generated during LaTeX compilation.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.log


Purpose: Contains the compilation log (errors, warnings).
Obtained: Generated by LaTeX during compilation.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.lot


Purpose: Stores the list of tables data.
Obtained: Generated during LaTeX compilation.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.nav


Purpose: Stores navigation data for Beamer presentations (table of contents).
Obtained: Generated automatically during compilation with the Beamer class.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.out


Purpose: Auxiliary file for additional metadata (e.g., Beamer overlays).
Obtained: Created during compilation, especially with classes like Beamer.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.snm


Purpose: Contains slide-specific information for Beamer presentations.
Obtained: Generated during compilation with the Beamer class.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.synctex[.gz]


Purpose: Allows synchronization between source and output (editor/viewer).
Obtained: Generated when -synctex=1 option is used.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.tmp


Purpose: Generic temporary files created by various LaTeX tools or editors.
Obtained: Automatically generated during compilation or editing.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.toc


Purpose: Stores table of contents data.
Obtained: Generated during LaTeX compilation.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.vrb


Purpose: Stores verbatim or code block content for certain environments (e.g., listings package).
Obtained: Generated during LaTeX compilation.
Safe to Remove: Yes.


.xdv


Purpose: Intermediate file produced by XeLaTeX (step before PDF generation).
Obtained: Automatically created when running XeLaTeX.
Safe to Remove: Yes, if the .pdf is present.

